# OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Product` model once compiled

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have tried to call my productSchema in my purchaseSchema but I've got this error: OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Product` model once compiled.
What can I try ?

It's my Schema of products:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productSchema = new Schema({

cd: {
    type: Number,
    require: true
},

nm_iten: {
    type: String,
    require: true
},

type_iten: {
    type: String,
    require: true
},

unity: {
    type: String,
    require: true
},

});
var product = mongoose.model('Product',productSchema);
module.exports = {product:product}
```

And, it's my purchase Schema:

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
   var productSchema = require('./products');
   var product = productSchema.product;

   var purchaseSchema = new Schema({

     code: {
       type: Number,
       require: true
    },

     product:[product],

     quant: {
       type: Number,
       require: true
    },

    vl_uni: {
       type: Number,
       require: true
     },

     vl_total: {
        type: Number,
        require: true
    }


    });
    mongoose.model('Purchase',purchaseSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the purchase schema, `product` need to point to the productSchema, not to the product model.

Product schema:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productSchema = new Schema({
    cd: {
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },    
    nm_iten: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },       
    type_iten: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },        
    unity: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },   
});
module.exports = productSchema;
```

Purchase schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var productSchema = require('./products');
var product = productSchema;

var purchaseSchema = new Schema({
   code: {
       type: Number,
       require: true
   },
   product:[product],
   quant: {
       type: Number,
       require: true
   },
   vl_uni: {
       type: Number,
       require: true
   },
   vl_total: {
       type: Number,
       require: true
   }
});
mongoose.model('Purchase',purchaseSchema);
```

See the mongodb docs about embedded documents for more info:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html